# In Azure App Service Settings, can I put a setting name with a $?

Tags: azure-appservice

I have an app that works locally but there's a failure in Azure which I believe it could be due to the fact that I have a setting name that contains a $ character: NAmespace:ComposerAdapters:CompanyAdapter:$kind = SlackAdapter

I'm putting that by hand in the configuration blade in Azure. And that adapter is not being loaded when deployed in Azure.

I couldn't find anywhere that I can't use $ in the name but it could be the problem.

Comment: You can refer to [Naming rules and restrictions for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules)

Comment: Hi! what would I use in that link? I couldn't find anything that talked about the settings name inside the Configuration of an App Service